# Master Calendar which displays all user Calendars

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, outlook, sync

It 'seems' like I can't do this but there's not a ton of information out there on SP 2016, so I'm trying to confirm.

Scenario:

We would like to have a single, master calendar on our SP 2016 site that would display all meetings, all absences, etc.  This can come from other section calendars that are overlaid, that's fine. However, what we want is that the data all syncs from the user's personal calendar.

From what I can tell, the only way to do this would be to create a SP calendar, have users connect to it, which essentially creates a 2nd calendar in their Outlook, and they now need to maintain 2 calendars?

Is this a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Yes but what you can do is, copy the events from outlook to SP calendar. That way they only have to maintain one calendar that is SP Calendar.!

Comment: Can you be more specific in how they would do this?  Is this a manual process?

Comment: Yes. Just connect your sharepoint calendar to outlook first.  The select your outlook calendar and change the view to list view and copy all events. Now, change your SharePoint calendar in outlook to list view and paste all the events!

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Calendar overlays are limited to 10 overlays per view. I think that creating views / overlays for everyone sounds crazy depending on how many people you have in your organization. Did you know that Outlook already gives your users the ability to open / view anyone else's calendar on the fly? Using the meeting scheduling assistant in Outlook allows you to cross check the attendees to see when they are open / busy.

Also when a user connects a SharePoint calendar to Outlook the overlays don't show up in Outlook as this is something that is only set up and seen in SharePoint.